# [Edit removed during grace period]

Tags: support, edits, grace-period

In the past, if you undid the changes after editing a post, the event would not show up in the revision history.

Today, I noticed that a new entry is created, [labelled "[Edit removed during grace period]"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/178403/revisions).

A [meta search for "[Edit removed during grace period]"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22Edit+removed+during+grace+period%22) did not show any results.
It's not listed in the [List of recent feature changes to Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59445/recent-feature-changes-to-stack-exchange) either.

When was this bug/feature introduced?